# How to render model with plain cartoon like colors

Tags: rendering, color-management

I just started to work with blender, finished my first models and i want to do some advanced things. 
My question is pretty simple: please see attached image. How do i achieve such rendering style in blender ( solid, plain cartoon-style colors) ? I'm not even sure how to google this, since i have no idea how this style is properly called.

Thanks!

[image: This is what i want :)]

Comment: thats achieved with textures , and flat materials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite easy. If using Blender Internal, simply make sure the ambient light is quite high so that shadow areas are not dark or black. Then set the Specularity value all the way down. That way the car will be red all over, but brighter red in the direction of the lamp.

For the headlights, set the material to Emit so that the colos will be completely flat.